# How to Execute loop without the element itself in the print results

Tags: python

I have an exercise that request me to send a message to each member in a list the I have created.
It doesn't says to send it to the other in the list without the element itself which is being currently in iterated but I decided to level up a bit this script.

What I want is: of of a list of lets say 5 person/ppl - I want to send the list of elements to a dedicated elements without the receiver to be in it.

For example:

If I have a list ['nora', 'adam', 'micheal', 'adrian']
So nora should get the list of ppl without nora to be included so she can see only the others
I hope you were able to follow up with me and answer directly

```
#Exercise 1 - guest list
#---------------------------------
guest = ['Rambam', 'Rambo', 'Hulk']
for i in guest:
    message = "Hello", i ,"I would like to invite you to my Dinner Party"
    print(', '.join(message))

#Exercise 2 - Changing guest list
print("\n")
not_coming = guest.pop(2)
new_comer = ['Superman']

#print(guest) - guest list testing

print(''.join(not_coming.title()), "won't be coming to the Dinner Party")
print("Therefore", new_comer[0], "will take place")
for i in guest:
    print(f"Hello", i, "please welcome", new_comer[0], "to the dinner party instead of hulk")
guest.append(new_comer[0])

#print(guest) - guest list testing
print("\n")

#Exercise 3

print("Hello all, I'm glad to announce that we have found a bigger table to have more guests to our party")
#Adding in the start middle and end of the list
#start
guest.insert(0, 'Ironman')
#print(guest) - testing 
#middle
mid = int(len(guest) / 2)
guest.insert(int(mid), 'Iceman')
#print(guest) - testing 
#End
guest.append('Spiderman')
#print(', '.join(guest)) - testing

#THIS IS WHERE IM FAILING WHAT IM TRYING TO DO 

for i in guest:
    print("Dear", i, "The order has changes and you will be joined in to the party with the following heroes")
    len(guest[i])
    elem = int(guest.pop(int(guest[i])))
    print(guest)
    guest.append(elem)
```

Comment: Having a list called 'guest' is probably a bad idea because it represents multiple guests, you should call it `guests` or `guest_list`

Comment: correct - just changed it

Answer (score 2):

When you use `for x in y:` x stores the variable itself, so you can check with an `if` the current object is equal to the one that's calling

The following sample have that behaviour

```
guest = ['Rambam', 'Rambo', 'Hulk']
for i in guest:
    newList = []
    for j in guest:
        if j != i:
            newList.append(j)

    print(newList)
```

`newList` will store all the guests *except* the one in the iteration

Comment: So simple it is brilliant - thanks!!  i apsolutely forgot to use if statments. 
(Im coming from comlete BASH  and having starting my way with Python as well s im taking it from the basics )

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function named "remove_me" for your task (It's better to use built-in function instead of for loop):

```
def remove_me(l,me):
    return list(set(l)- set([me]))
```

testing:

```
guest = ['Rambam', 'Rambo', 'Hulk']
res = remove_me(guest,'Hulk')
```

returns:

```
['Rambam', 'Rambo']
```

Comment: Just to undersatnd : In the defination action the "1" is the key and, "me" is the value?

Answer (score 0):

This is where list comprehension comes in very handy, `[guest for guest in guest_list if guest != current_guest]` Gives you a list of all guests who are not current_guest which you can use however you need to.

```
guest_list = ['Rambo','Spiderman','Hulk']

for current_guest in guest_list:
    other_guests = [guest for guest in guest_list if guest != current_guest]
    print("your Name", current_guest)
    print("Other Guests:",other_guests )
```

Comment: Just to understand : in here tou are comparing every value to itself and together also make en exepction for the current irritation right ?

Comment: It's functionally identical to FanGoH's answer, just another way of achieving the same result which has pros and cons.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use list comprehension in your code like this:

```
for i in guest:
    print("Dear", i, "The order has changes and you will be joined in to the party with the following heroes")
    print([for g in guest if g != i])
```

Note: list comprehensions creates new list, so it will not interfere into your current iteration/loop.